# Next record doesnt exist error handling

Tags: php, mysql

I have this bit of code that goes to the next record in the database based on the record id, when it gets to the last record the next time you click it the code breaks due to the record not existing in the table and the url not being valid.  Is there some error handling i could put into this to show an alert when the last record has been reached?  Thanks

```
<a id="next" data-ajax="true"  href="eventviewtester.php?eventid= <?php echo $_GET['eventid'] +1;?>" style="display:none;"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you are dealing with a degenerate form of pagination - the case where you are paginating a single record at a time.  As such, you should use typically pagination methodology which requires that you understand the size of the total possible result set and where within that result set you are.

I would recommend going away from blindly relying on `row id + 1` for paginated viewing as this mechanism may not be reliable (for example what happens if you delete a row from the table leaving a gap in the number sequence?). You should perform a `LIMIT X,Y` type of query on your table to understand specifically the rows you are dealing with.  Perhaps in your case that means getting a group of two records at a time so you can display the current record as well as display a link to the next record (or not show a `next` link if you have reached the upper record limit and your query only returned a single record).

Here are some query suggestions.

This would get the currently selected record plus the next highest one. If only one row is returned, this is the last record

```
SELECT [fields]
FROM [table]
WHERE eventid >= [value from GET]
ORDER BY eventid ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Or if you you want to deal in terms of "pages" i.e. not rely on event id itself, but rather event in X position

```
SELECT [fields]
FROM [table]
ORDER BY eventid ASC
LIMIT X,1
```

Here X would be a zero-based value such that if you wanted 10th event in ascending order, you would pass a value of 9.  Here you don't need to know the next event id number (you can just call for page number 11 in link from page 10), so we only return 1 record.  Of course, to understand the total number of pages you would need to perform an additional simple query to determine the number of rows in the table.

Since you have mentioned in your comments that you want to try the eventid based approach, then I think the first query is what you would need to go with.  So when you read the result set, obviously the first record will contain the data that you need for displaying on the current page.  You then need to get the eventid information from the second record and use this in building your query string.

```
// you would grab next event id in your second iteration through the DB result set
$next_event_id = $row['eventid'];

// then use it when building your URL reference
echo '<a id="next" data-ajax="true"  href="eventviewtester.php?eventid=' . $next_event_id . '" style="display:none;"></a>';
```

Comment: Can you give me more information or an example of how to do this?

Comment: @Steven There are a number of examples of pagination queries in SO and the internet at large.  I have added a couple example pagination queries to my answer to hopefully get you started.

Comment: one other question.  How would i change my anchor tag to go to the next record?  the way the page works is that its a single view of a record, so thats why i intially went with a hacky approach of eventid + 1 for the url.  Thanks.

Comment: thats the only thing missing then i can approve your answer as accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: @Steven That depends on whether you want your application to deal in terms of pages in the URL or event id's.  With a pages concept, the same event ID might end up on a different page depending on whether items before it were deleted or inserted.  With the event id approach, your URL will always remain the same for an individual event id, but the next event might change.  So really the approach is determined by your desired user experience.

Comment: I will be using or at least trying the eventid approach.  So how would i handle that anchor? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Find the total number of records and then display the link if the count is less than or equal to that number.

```
// FIND TOTAL RECORD COUNT
$number_of_records = 20;

// CHECK TO SEE IF THE COUNT IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO THE TOTAL 
if ($_GET['eventid'] + 1 <= $number_of_records) {
    echo '<a id="next" data-ajax="true"  href="eventviewtester.php?eventid='.($_GET['eventid'] + 1).'" style="display:none;">Link Text</a>';
}
else {
    echo 'Non-Link Text';
}
```

Comment: could I get the max of the event id and do anything less than or equal to that?  And how would i implement this into already existing HTML?

Comment: Yes, getting the max for the eventid would accomplish exactly the same thing.  As far as putting it in your existing HTML, just use the standard PHP tags to insert your code.  PHP was designed for this.  For example, if you wanted to insert PHP code into a table cell, you could do something like this:

`<tr><td><?php echo $php_stuff; ?></td></tr>`

Comment: @Quickrick this is what i have and its giving me an error on line 9 unexpected }

Comment: <?php
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT max['event_id'] FROM events GROUP BY event_id");
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
   {
$number_of_records = $row1['event_id'];

if ($_GET['eventid'] + 1 <= $number_of_records) {?>
    <a id="next" data-ajax="true"  href="eventviewtester.php?eventid='.($_GET['eventid'] + 1).'" style="display:none;"></a>
<?php}
else{?>
<?php echo 'Record Doesnt Exist';
 }
 ?>

Comment: You have an error in your MySQL syntax.  MAX should be used like this:

mysql_query("SELECT MAX(event_id) FROM events");

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, just try this. Use count value for getting the number of records.

```
if($count>$_GET['eventid']){
<a id="next" data-ajax="true"  href="eventviewtester.php?eventid= <?php echo $_GET['eventid'] +1;?>" style="display:none;"></a>
}
```